# ScriptLab Excel add-in causes Excel and WWAHost.exe application errors

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

I installed the ScriptLab add-in and the tab appears in the Excel ribbon but when I select any of the functions Excel closes and several error log entries are created.  The first is an application error entry (1000) with the following content:

```
    Faulting application name: wwahost.exe, version: 10.0.19041.1, time stamp: 0x484cb762
    Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.207, time stamp: 0x746c1866
    Exception code: 0xc0000409
    Fault offset: 0x000000000010b37c
    Faulting process id: 0x2140
    Faulting application start time: 0x01d63e4a6dd4b061
    Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\wwahost.exe
    Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
    Report Id: 572aaded-81e8-42ba-89da-5a7277de68d2
    Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_10.0.19041.1_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
    Faulting package-relative application ID: DPI.PerMonitorAware
```

A second application error entry is logged :

```
    Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.12827.20268, time stamp: 0x5ed0d679
    Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.207, time stamp: 0x746c1866
    Exception code: 0xc0000409
    Fault offset: 0x000000000010b37c
    Faulting process id: 0x3554
    Faulting application start time: 0x01d63e4a38fafc7d
    Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
    Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
    Report Id: 0576eb2c-8a99-4a8f-a97c-5e8f80f765f8
    Faulting package full name: 
    Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Each of the error entries are followed by Windows Error Reporting entries.

**My environment is:**

**OS :** Windows 10 Home Version 2004 build 19041.264

**Office:** version 2005 Build 12827.20268 Click-to-Run

**Edge Version:** Version 83.0.478.45 (Official build) (64-bit)

**Edge Beta:** Version 84.0.522.15 (Official build) beta (64-bit)

I have re-installed Edge and Edge Beta, fixed Office installation, ran sfc /scannow with no errors.

Any ideas where to look will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the web view control issue, i would suggest that create an issue at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues, team who responsible for this area will follow up

Comment: Thanks Raymond - I have done so